# How to distinguish between native vs hybrid mobile application?

Tags: android, native, hybrid-mobile-app

Given an Android app (.apk), is there a way to know if it is native application or hybrid application?

Answer (score 2):

First of all unzip the apk. If it's hybrid, you will see .html, .js and .css files in the /res/assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

Response times are generally a give away. Remember hybrid pieces are mostly trying to download assets on the fly.

A good read for native vs hybrid mobile will be: [Link](https://navdeepmahajantechblogs.blogspot.com/?m=1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a simple way to distinguish between hybrid and native app.
Go to Developer Options from Settings and turn on Show Layout bounds.
And then launch your app and see the layout highlighted. If there are lots of rectangle highlighted, it's native. Otherwise hybrid.